# Delphi project asks to save without making changes

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Every time I open the project group without making any changes, the save button is enabled and when I close the projects, IDE always asks to save one of the projects.

Of the three projects of the group, with only one of them, and always with the same thing happens.

And it happens every time I log in `.groupproj` or `.dpr` in question, however much I have not made any changs.

By checking the project files, after clicking "yes" to save the "changes", the files remain identical, except for the `.identcache`, which has small changes each time the project is opened.

This is disrupting me in a process that I need to run periodically, so I would like to resolve.

I'm using `Embarcadero Delphi 10.2`

Comment: This is a common situation since 10.1. Something changed so that the IDE always modifies at least 1 file when you open the project, even if you yourself change nothing. It used to be (10.0) that you could run 2 copies of 1 application, one by "run without debugging" and the other by debugging, but the automatic file change gets in the way of that since 10.1. I live with it. They might fix it one day. (10.3?)